# OR sentence example in PROPEL

Tags: php, propel

im learning about propel, in documentation i found examples about WHERE/AND WHERE/IN  but i cant found examples for WHERE/OR. How i can make this SQL in propel?

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='carasuman' OR `email`='carasuman@host.com';
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you didn't read the docs related to model criteria, where the OR-clause is covered in detail.

http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria#combining_several_conditions

Comment: well, I'm blind, took 2 hours reading about propel and did not see that. Tanks you so much windvds